# isolating specific values in external .js array

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement

I'm currently trying to populate a selection list from an external javascript array. It works but I'm trying to populate only certain values using an ID column, which is failing. I'm using check-boxes and an 'If' statement to see which box is checked, and populate the appropriate array values based on this selection. I'm then using another 'If' within a for loop to match the ID value in the array, and add the matching values to the selection. However, it seems that it is completely disregarding the condition and reading the entire array in to selection list. It could be an obvious mistake with my code as I am only a novice.

function populateIslandList () {

```
        var form = document.forms["island_form"];
        var islands = form.islands;
        if (islands[0].checked){alert("works");
            for (i = 0; i < pislands.length; i++)
            if (pislands[i][1] = 1){
            document.forms["location"].islands.options[i] =
            new Option(pislands[i][0], i)}};
        if (islands[1].checked){alert("works");
            for (i = 0; i < pislands.length; i++)
            if (pislands[i][1] = 2){
            document.forms["location"].islands.options[i] =
            new Option(pislands[i][0], i)}};    
        }
```

Comment: Please post all of your code, and really you should create a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/). But right away it looks like you are trying to grab two elements by ID. Only one element can have one ID.

Answer (score 0):

Your first mistake is here:

```
var islands = document.getElementById("island_form");
```

`document.getElementById()` returns a single DOM element, not a list of objects.  So, thus `islands[0]` and `islands[1]` are going to be undefined and `islands[0].checked` will make a script error.

You can only have one DOM element with a given id.  You can have multiple elements with a class name so maybe you should switch to using class names and be using `document.getElementsByClassName("something")`

---

FYI, you should be looking in the browser error console or debug console to see script errors as this should have given you an indication of some trouble here.